Transiting Through the US With Separate Itineraries
I have a Pakistani passport with a valid B1/B2 U.S. visa and lives in Jamaica. My flight itinerary includes:

A return ticket booked with American Airlines from Kingston (KIN) to Miami (MIA).
A separate return ticket booked with Turkish Airlines from Miami (MIA) to Jeddah (JED).

To absorb any potential delays, I have made sure to book a 24-hour stay in Miami. Could booking these tickets separately create issues during immigration or with the airlines?
I am particularly concerned about proof of onward travel, baggage transfer, and transiting through the U.S. with separate itineraries.

The main issue would be a substantial delay of your flight into Miami, either outbound or returning, causing you to miss your next flight leaving Miami.
Since you hold a valid US visa, there should be no issue with onward travel nor entering the U.S. to transit. You will have to pick up your bags and check them in separately during your layover in Miami since you are on different tickets and American Airlines will not check them all the way: https://saleslink.aa.com/en-US/documents/Archives/AgencyRef/Baggage-Through_Checked_Baggage_Policy-Separate_Tickets.pdfand

+1, you'd have to pick up your bags and take them through Customs even on a single ticket, since the US doesn't do sterile transit.
